# What is the use of this object in the cockpit of a Bombardier Dash 8 Q400?

Tags: cockpit, feature-identification, bombardier, dash-8

What is the use of this object in the  cockpit of a Bombardier Dash 8 Q400?

[image: Dash-8 cockpit]

Answer (score 5):

It is a mechanical checklist where each item on the list can be flipped to indicate that is has been checked. You can see it in operation in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsRg4iNtZV0) (which I believe is where you got the image from). Each of the 6 stacks can be extended to check the items and then collapsed again in order to not obstruct the pilot's view.

It is not a default part of the Dash-8 Q400. As far as I know, Qantas is the only airline using it.

Comment: Thank you dear friend 